# C# extension to resolve cross thread exception

Tags: c#, multithreading

Is there any extension method available for resolving cross thread exception in windows forms like the one which is there for wpf forms.or any general pattern..

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37314/Useful-WPF-Threading-Extension-Method.aspx

Comment: Can you show the code you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Invoke` already does *some* things to short-circuit here, but it would be trivial to make it complete:

```
public static class SyncExtensions {
    public static void InvokeIfRequired(this ISynchronizeInvoke ctrl,
            MethodInvoker method) {
        if(ctrl.InvokeRequired) ctrl.Invoke(method, null);
        else method();
    }
}
```

The choice of `MethodInvoker` is since this has specific handling inside `Invoke` to avoid having to use `DynamicInvoke` (reflection).

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at the [BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke.aspx) Method?